# os_log fault message produces "Activity for state dumps"

Tags: swift, oslog

I'm working on a logger that is based on Unified Logging System that supports activities/scopes and I've found that a message with `fault` level type is not captured by any of my activities:

```swift
var os_state = os_activity_scope_state_s()
let os_activity = _os_activity_create(dso, strdup("My Activity"), OS_ACTIVITY_CURRENT, OS_ACTIVITY_FLAG_DEFAULT)
os_activity_scope_enter(os_activity, &os_state)

os_log("fault message", type: .fault) // "My Activity" don't have one

os_activity_scope_leave(&os_state)
```

Later I found the activity with my message:

```
16:04:52.978940+0300    libsystem_trace.dylib   0   Activity for state dumps
```

So the system creates a special activity for that kind of messages (Tested on Mac/iOS).

But from the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/oslogtype/2320725-fault):

> If an activity object exists, logging at this level captures information for the entire process chain.

And it's the same as for the `error` log level which is captured OK for custom activities.

Is a known issue or expected behaviour? I can't find any info about.

Comment: from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging/collecting_log_messages_in_activities) it seems like they are calling a different func like os_log_fault not os_log. Did try that?

Comment: @zombie OSLog is limited on Swift and there are no that methods but you are right it's interesting to test on objc.

Comment: Objc `os_log_fault` produces new activity as well so it's a common behaviour.